# relation between DFT to CTFT

Tags: sampling, dft, continuous-signals, dtft

The signal $$x(t)\;\;\;\;0\leq t\leq 0.2s $$

We know that the CTFT of $x(t)=0$ when $|w|>2*\pi*10^4$

We sample $x(t)$ in sample space of $$T=25\mu s$$ or $$F_s=1/T=40000Hz$$and we get a series with length of 8000.

$$x[n]=x(nT)\;\;\;\;0\leq n \leq 7999 $$

We calculate the DFT of $x[n]$ in size 8000 also.

What is the relation between the CTFT to the DFT

$$X^F(\omega) \rightarrow X_N^d[k]$$

The answer is:

$$
\begin{equation}
  X_N^d[k]=\begin{cases}
    \dfrac{N}{T}X^F(10\pi k), & 0\leq k\leq 3999\\ \\
    \dfrac{N}{T}X^F(10\pi (k-8000)), & 4000\leq k\leq 7999
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$

Comment: Do you also submitted the answer? I am bit confused about your objective.

Comment: I have the answer but I don’t know how to solve the problem.

Comment: The relationship between the spectrum of $X(f)$ of discrete time signal and the spectrum $X_a(F)$ of the analog signal is $$X(f)=F_s\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}X_a\left[(f-k)F_s\right]$$

On right-hand side is the periodic repetition of the scaled spectrum, scaled with period $F_s$

Comment: Proof is in Digital Signal Processing  - Proakis

Comment: @jomegaA I don't understand how to get to the answer from what you wrote here.

Comment: the proof is in Digital Signal Processing - Proakis

Comment: I don't need to proof anything. I know this formula... I just don't understand how they solve it.

Comment: With proof I meant, the solution to your problem. Its easy. Please take a look!!!

Comment: @jomegaA I read about that in the book but I didn't find something that help me to solve this problem.

Comment: DSP - Proakis 3rd edition page 269 "The Sampling Theorem Revisited"

Comment: I saw this, but for what I am understand they explain about the connection about DTFT to CTFT and not DFT.

Comment: page 394-397 (Frequency Domain Sampling)

Comment: I am not a math guy so I can't derive any relationship between CTFT to DFT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's give it a shot.

We know that during sampling, we obtained a discretized version, $x(nT_s)$ of a continuous time signal $x(t)$ sampled every $T_s$ seconds. I will denote their corresponding Fourier Transforms as $X_{DT}(e^{j\omega})$ and $X_{CT}(j\Omega)$, respectively, according to the majority of the bibliography. Indices denote *discrete time (DT)* and *continuous-time (CT)* Fourier Transforms.

The Discrete time Fourier Transform (DTFT) of the sampled signal is given by $$X_{DT}(e^{j\omega}) = \frac{1}{T_s}\sum_{l=-\infty}^{+\infty}X_{CT}\Big(j\Big(\frac{\omega}{T_s} - l\frac{2\pi l}{T_s}\Big)\Big)$$

Assuming that there is no aliasing (like in your case), over one period this turns into $$X_{DT}(e^{j\omega}) = \frac{1}{T_s}X_{CT}\Big(j\frac{\omega}{T_s}\Big)$$

Due to the $2\pi$-periodic nature of the DTFT and the fact that we're dealing with real-valued signals, we can rewrite this as $$X_{DT}(e^{j\omega}) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{1}{T_s}X_{CT}\Big(j\frac{\omega}{T_s}\Big), & 0 \leq \omega < \pi \\
\frac{1}{T_s}X_{CT}\Big(j\frac{\omega-2\pi}{T_s}\Big), & \pi \leq \omega < 2\pi \\
\end{array}\right.$$

The Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) is an $N-$point uniformly sampled version of the DTFT, so $$X_{DFT}[k] = X_{DT}(e^{j\omega})\Big|_{\omega = 2\pi k/N}$$ for $0 \leq k\leq N-1$.

Combining the last two equations we have $$X_{DFT}[k] = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{1}{T_s}X_{CT}\Big(j\frac{2\pi k}{NT_s}\Big), & 0 \leq k < N/2 \\
\frac{1}{T_s}X_{CT}\Big(j\frac{2\pi (k-N)}{NT_s}\Big), & N/2 \leq k \leq N-1 \\
\end{array}\right.$$

Except for the constant $N$ in your results - that I have failed to extract - I think what I wrote will help you.

Comment: The constant N is for approximately result. thanks!